# Laplace Transform of a impulse sampled function through convolution property

Tags: complex-numbers, improper-integrals, laplace-transform, convolution, control-theory

I'm reading Katsuhijo Ogata's book "Discrete Time control Systems", at some point convolution property is used to get the Laplace transform of a function sampled with impulse train. Here I'm using $j=\sqrt{-1}$

Impulse sampled function:  $x_m(t)= x(t)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \delta (t-nT) \quad $   **(1)**

Laplace transform: $\mathcal{L} [ x_m(t) ]= X_m (s)  \quad $ **(2)**

Convolution Property: $ X_m(s)= \frac{1}{j 2 \pi}\int_{c-j\infty }^{c+j\infty } X(k) \frac{1}{1-e^{-T(s-k)} }dk \quad $ **(3)**

I understand a countour like the image below, where $R \rightarrow \infty $   is used to solve **(3)** 
[image]

The closed integral equals the sum of the two lines integrals ($\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$). That is:

$\oint{X(k) \frac{1}{1-e^{-T(s-k)} }dk}=\frac{1}{j 2 \pi}\int_{\Gamma_1}{X(k) \frac{1}{1-e^{-T(s-k)} }dk}+\frac{1}{j 2 \pi}\int_{\Gamma_2}{X(k) \frac{1}{1-e^{-T(s-k)} }dk}$

It is assumed that $X(k)$ es a rational function of p-Polynomials with two cases:

1) The denominator is greater in 2 or more orders than the numerator (page 146). That means:

$\lim_{s \rightarrow \infty} sX(s)= 0$

In this case, the integral over the curved part fades as $R \rightarrow \infty$.

$ \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{1}{j 2 \pi}  \int_{\Gamma_1} {X(k) \frac{1}{1-e^{-T(s-k)} }dk}= 0 \quad$                 **(4)**

So **(3)** reduces to:

$\oint{X(k) \frac{1}{1-e^{-T(s-k)} }dk} = \int_{\Gamma_2}{X(k) \frac{1}{1-e^{-T(s-k)} }dk}$

2) The denominator is only one order greater than the denominator (page 148), that means:

$\lim_{s \rightarrow \infty} sX(s)= x(0+)$

In this case, the book states that "it can be proved that":

$\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{j 2 \pi}  \int_{\Gamma_1} {X(k) \frac{1}{1-e^{-T(s-k)} }dk}= -\frac{1}{2} x(0+) \quad $    **(5)**

So **(3)** reduces to:

$\oint{X(k) \frac{1}{1-e^{-T(s-k)} }dk} = \int_{\Gamma_2}{X(k) \frac{1}{1-e^{-T(s-k)} }dk} +\frac{1}{2} x(0+) $

**My question is about (4) and (5), what is the approach to get to these conclusions?**

I'm fully aware that it isn't required to know this to advance with the reading, but i really want to know the reason of those conclusions.

---

So far I've tried to to define $X(k)$ (for case 2) as :

$X(k)=\frac{\prod_{n=1}^{N} (k-z_n) } {\prod_{n=1}^{N+1} (k-p_n)} $

Set $k=x+jy$   and   $y=\pm \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}$ and try to solve the line integral as:

$\int_{c}^{R} X(x+j\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}) \frac{1}{1-e^{-T(s-x-j\sqrt{R^2 - x^2})}}dx + \int_{R}^{c} X(x-j\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}) \frac{1}{1-e^{-T(s-x+j\sqrt{R^2 - x^2})}}dx$

Then trying partial integration with complex functions $g(x)=\frac{1}{1-e^{-T(s-x-j\sqrt{R^2 - x^2})}}$  and  $F(x)=X(x+j\sqrt{R^2 - x^2})$  :

$\int_{c}^{R} F(x) g(x) dx= \left( F(x) G(x) \right) \bigg\rvert_{c}^{R} - 
 \int_{c}^{R} f(x) G(x) dx$

Where $f(x)= \frac{d}{dx} F(x)$ and $G(x)=\int g(x)dx$.

Problem with this approach is just getting $G(X)$ is enough to make me to think I'm doing something wrong. Help me with some guide or reference please.